# How to insert in mongoDB my own id of an object (from Java)

Tags: java, json, mongodb, collections, database

I am making a java application and I want to insert some data in my mongoDB but I want to replace the default id with my property

Here is my code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("indexdb");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("indexCollection");
        for (Map.Entry<String, ReduceResult> rr : directindex.entrySet()) {
            BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("DOC", rr.getKey() );
            Map<String,Integer>wordmap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> r : rr.getValue().getIndexedFile().entrySet()) {
                wordmap.put(r.getKey(), r.getValue());
            }
            doc.append("terms", wordmap);
            coll.insert(doc);
        }
```

The output is

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58e5889ce4b02461ad5af080"} , "DOC" : "/home/ion/Desktop/RIW/input/doc4" , "terms" : { "dan" : 1 , "gutui" : 1}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58e5889ce4b02461ad5af081"} , "DOC" : "/home/ion/Desktop/RIW/input/doc3" , "terms" : { "bune" : 1 , "gutui" : 1}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58e5889ce4b02461ad5af082"} , "DOC" : "/home/ion/Desktop/RIW/input/doc2" , "terms" : { "dan" : 1 , "mere" : 2}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58e5889ce4b02461ad5af083"} , "DOC" : "/home/ion/Desktop/RIW/input/doc1" , "terms" : { "ana" : 1 , "mere" : 1 , "pere" : 1}}
```

But I want to insert without that "_id" I want the id of my object to be "DOC"
Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you can remove `_id` field altogether. Either map the `DOC` values to `_id` or keep the way it is and query on `DOC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own field and call it... "id". There you will store the ids you want.

In the schema of your collection you can tell Mongo not to create automatic ids like so:

```
// disabled id
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
var Page = mongoose.model('Page', schema);
var p = new Page({ name: 'mongodb.org' });
console.log(p.id); // undefined
```

from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html